# How to parse JSON format DATA from Facebook Graph Api with php?

Tags: php, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I wrote this php code to fetch data from an url with json format and It seemed like it worked but I dont get anything in the database

```
      <?php 
     session_start();
     $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect     to mysql"); 
    mysqli_select_db($con,"facebook_data") or die ("no database"); 
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/209024949216061/feed?fields=created_time,from,type,message&access_token=XXXXXXXX";
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);

   $data = json_decode($curlResponse,TRUE);
 if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
 foreach($data as $row){

     $id=$row["id"];
     $created_time=$row["created_time"];
     $type=$row["type"];
     $message=$row["message"];
     $user_id=$row["from"]["id"];
     $username=$row["from"]["name"];

     $sql="INSERT INTO group_feed(id, username, created_time, user_id, type, message) VALUES('$id','$username','$created_time','$user_id', '$type', '$message')";
       if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
       {
    die('Error : ');
       }
     }
   }

 ?>
```

I put the $url with the appropriate access_token when I open the link in my browser it displays me the JSON format DATA where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

`$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$group_id."/feed/?access_token=".$token;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);`

Check http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for more information on `curl()`

Then you have to parse you curl response using `$data = json_decode($curlResponse)`. You will get an associative array which can be iterated (`foreach`, `for`, `while`).
Only you know how to write your SQL queries.

Note: If this doesn't work, take a look at the `curl_setopt()` function.